# Read/send data in android and c# Bluetooth Communication : c# <-> Android

Tags: c#, android, web-services, bluetooth

I have developed a web application in C#  and an android app. Web app(c#) is acting as a server and attached to SQL server 2008 R2 while android is acting as client and it communicates with web app(C#) via bluetooth( bluetooth coding is done in c# winforms).

Now one thing I know is that android cannot directly communicate with SQL database for it I have to utilize web service. I wanted to authenticate my android app login/register from web app(C#)

My winform(C#) in which bluetooth(using feet32 library) functionality is implement should act as an agent between client(android) and server(C#).
Now I wanted to know that:

1. How my winform application will act as an agent to communicate with client and server both and read/send data to and fro.
2. If I need web service to implement then in which application I should write in webapp or winform?
3. I wanted to authenticate my android app login/register from web app(C#). I f I have to write for it webservice then whether I will write it in web app or winform?

I am just a beginner and its my final project. Please help me to understand the complete scenario and my knowledge is too little and also if there is any good tutorial for any of these functionality please do mention the link .. 
Thanks

**Edited:** After little Research I come to know about SOAP http web service, What you guys think where to implement this web service according to above questions.

Comment: too broad for S.O ......

Comment: user2684131, Of course, but I have no time to write a book right now...

Comment: @14V I am not asking for whole code I am just asking how to do it . just provide idea :)

Comment: user2684131,  this is the problem. You should get the idea somehow, write some code and if you get stuck somewhere ask here. SO is about coding. Not about general ideas.

Comment: @14V thats where I stuck, thats is why I am asking here.

Answer (score 0):

To establish communication between two devices by using Web services you don't have to use winform application.

You can establish a connection via web services, just create a new ASP.NET project using visual studio then add a Web service and folloe the template it gives you.

Right click on the service, click on view in browser, verify there is no any error. The address of this browser is the address of your service just connect to this service from the second device.

Please check out this guideline: [CodeProject Web Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337535/Understanding-the-Basics-of-Web-Service-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: thanks for link, its quite helpful. I think you forget about bluetooth I am connected android and c# via bluetooth functionality for which I write winform app. Now I want my winform app to communicate with web app( which is main app and server + connected with sql server) and also with android. If required more information please do ask,

Comment: I think for this scenario webservices are best. I wanted to utilize JSON. can you please direct me towards good learning tutorials of JSON webservices.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ICE](http://www.zeroc.com/android.html), It got excellent cross platform support and is open source. I have been using it for last four years to communicate between c++ and C# applications.

[ICE for .Net](http://www.zeroc.com/icedotnet.html)

[ICE for Android](http://www.zeroc.com/android.html)